# How do you know when to stop applying single responsibility principle in React components?

Tags: reactjs

In ReactJS, I get the point of SRP. But I think I'm thinking about it the wrong way. My problem is I don't know when to stop with regards to SRP. Like for the example in [Thinking in React](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html). I could easily say that the `ProductRow` component could be further be broken down to this:

- `ProductRow` - displays a row for each product

  - `ProductRowName` - displays the name for each product row
  - `ProductRowPrice` - displays the price for each product row

My question now is, how do you know when enough is enough for SRP? What's your cue? I'm hoping to pick up how react devs think so I could apply it on my codes.

Answer (score 0):

Functionality first.

The great thing about react is how it handles reusability of your code.  You want to take advantage of that as much as possible.  And to best do that, I think both the example *and* your changes to it fall short of the real goal.

What is the functionality of `ProductRow`?  It's meant to take in an object and then output a table row with information from that object.

If we define exactly *what* the object is, or exactly *which pieces of the object* should be output, then we've boxed ourselves into a corner.  `ProductRow` is now only usable for product objects, and requires that those objects have a name and price attribute.

Can we strip some of that specificity out?  Can we make a component that has a single responsibility, but without dictating the shape of it's input?

Sure!

```
var Row = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var item = this.props.item;
    var columnNames = this.props.columnNames;
    return (
      <tr>
        {columnNames.map(function(columnName){
            return <td> {item[columnName]} </td>;
        })}
      </tr>
    );
  }
});

//USAGE:  <Row item={product} columnNames={['name', 'price']} />
```

Now the failing here is that we no longer have unique formatting per column (red name depending on stock status).  But **that** is where we actually reach an issue for SRP.  It's time to make a second component, who's responsibility is to create a color map, based on conditions of the input.